# Error in making array of class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ptc-windchill

I have got below code snippet after decompiling a java class file. The original class was created in java 1.4. Now I am trying to compile in Java 1.6. I am using eclipse Juno.

```
Public class[] getClassTypes()
 {
return (new class[] {wt.part.WTPart});
}
```

But when I compile it I get the error 'wt.part.WTPart can not be resolved to a variable'

When I browse in my eclipse WS, I can see class WTPart is present in my project. 
Is decompiler has missed something/syntax error?

My understanding from this code is that this method just returns a list of class.

Updte:

```
    import wt.part.WTPart;
    ...
    ...

Public class[] getClassTypes()
 { WTPart a= new WTPart();
  wt.part.WTPart b= new wt.part.WTPart();

return (new class[] {wt.part.WTPart});
}
```

I don't get error at the creation of a and b. Only at the return statement I get this error.
Thanks

Comment: `WTPart` is exist, how about `wt`/`part`?

Comment: One thing I forget to mention that decompiler produced it like 'wt/part/WTPart'. But than I thought that may be I need to replace '/' with '.'. I have linked a external class folder 'Codebase'. Inside this is a wt directory and inside that is a part directory. In the begining of java file an import statement is there 'Import wt.part.WTPart'. There I don't get any compilation error.

Comment: if you want to use 'wt.part.WTPart` you need to put package name `wt.part.WTPart`

Comment: So that means, I need to create a package name 'wt.part.WTPart' and copy these class files inside that.

Comment: inside all your class within `part` directory, write this line `package wt.part;`

Comment: I don't have java file for WTPart.

Comment: Actually I am using a lot of class files. These are like libraries. Why I need to create packages foe these files. Why can't I access code from these class files directly.

Comment: package is not necessary, but don't use `wt.part.WTPart`, it should only your class name which is `WTPart`

Comment: Please check that last line is a valid syntax or not in java 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the '.class', and the 'class[]' should be upper case : 'Class[]'

```
return (new Class[] {wt.part.WTPart.class});
```